# How to make an info window clickable?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have the below code, based on one of the API samples. A click on the map creates a marker. A click on the marker opens up an info window. Now I want a click on the info window to do something. E.g. a click anywhere might close it, as opposed to the little cross in the corner. Or a click on it might open a new URL. Etc.

Unfortunately it seems there is no "click" event for info windows.

The closest I've got is shown as a commented out line below: I wrap my info window content in a div, and give that an `onClick`. This works, but there is a big border around it. I really want to be able to click anywhere in the info window box.

Is there a way?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Click Test</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;   //New look visuals.

function initialize() {
  var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
  var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map-canvas");

  if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
    mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
    mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
  } else {
    mapdiv.style.width = '400px';
    mapdiv.style.height = '600px';
  }

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom:3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -95.712891),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });

function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
        });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        //content: "<div onClick='test1()'>(lat,lng):<br/>"+location.lat()+","+location.lng()+"</div>"
        content: "(lat,lng):<br/>"+location.lat()+","+location.lng()
        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
        infowindow.addListener('click',test1);  //Does nothing
        });

    }

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function test1(){alert("test1");}

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE:**
This image shows the problem when I use a clickable `div` inside the content (background set to red to show the extent of the region I can make clickable, and also that I can style; if I set a negative margin I just get scrollbars, not a bigger region!). It is the whole white area I want to be clickable, not just that red rectangle.
[image]

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999858/google-map-api-v3-click-on-marker-show-more-info-content-as-overlay-like-in-g

Comment: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/?

Comment: javascript http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js

Comment: @RachelGallen Thanks for the three links. They are a bit enigmatic, can you expand on why you gave them? I think the first is a different question; the answer only shows clicking on markers to make an info window, which I already do. For the other two comments, are you saying if I switch from InfoWindow to InfoBubble then I can achieve what I need, i.e. make the whole pop-up clickable? Thanks!

Comment: The info window can take any DOM element as its contents. So you should be able to attach events to that DOM element using whatever method you prefer (I generally like to use jQuery).

Comment: @ShadowCreeper Thanks. I think you are suggesting what is shown with the commented-out line in my example (that wraps my content in a `div`). But it leaves quite a big border around my content that isn't clickable. If you are suggesting something different I'd love to see some code showing your approach. Thanks!

Comment: @DarrenCook You should also be able to add whatever styling you need to your div for setting `margin:0;padding:0;border:none` etc. Oh, I see, there are 3 parent divs that force a padding :(

Comment: @ShadowCreeper Thanks for the reply. I've added an image to my question to show the limit of this approach.

Comment: @DarrenCook the links given are to do with the infobubble gunctionality , about the only thing that will make you able to put clickable items in an info window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to use InfoBox found in the [Google Maps Utility Library](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries). So in the header add a link to the library. Then replace the `new google.maps.InfoWindow()` line with this one:

```
var infowindow = new InfoBox({
    closeBoxURL:"",
    content: '<div onClick="test1();return false;" style="background:white;opacity:0.8;padding:8px">(lat,lng):<br/>'+
        location.lat()+","+location.lng()+"</div>"
    });
```

By setting closeBoxUrl to a blank string I get no close option. I added a large padding just so you can see that clicking right to the edge does indeed work.

You can also do it this way. I also use the boxClass option so the formatting is done in CSS:

```
var infoContent=document.createElement('div');
infoContent.innerHTML="(lat,lng):<br/>"+location.lat()+","+location.lng();
infoContent.onclick=test1;
var infowindow = new InfoBox({
    closeBoxURL:"",
    boxClass:"marker_popup",
    content: infoContent,
    });
```

(Aside, if doing it this way, on just some browsers it creates a marker below the InfoBox! Simplest fix is to change `test1` so it looks like: `function test1(event){alert("test1");event.preventDefault();return false;}` )

P.S. I chose InfoBox over InfoBubble, as the latter has no documentation, and it had no obvious advantages to compensate for that major flaw! InfoBox has [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/docs/examples.html) and [a reference](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/docs/reference.html#InfoBoxOptions).  (links are for version 1.1.9)